# i am trying to trim audio file in php using getID3 library.i got a random string.How to convert it proper file.that can be played

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to trim audio file in php using getID3 library.I got a random string. How to convert it proper file.that can be played

```
$getID3 = new getID3(); 

$id3_info = $getID3->analyze('assets/upload/'.$new_audio_name); 

list($t_min, $t_sec) = explode(':', $id3_info['playtime_string']);
$time = ($t_min * 60) + $t_sec;

$preview = $time / 30; // Preview time of 30 seconds

$handle = fopen('assets/upload/'.$new_audio_name, 'r');
$content = fread($handle,filesize('assets/upload/'.$new_audio_name));

$length = strlen($content);

$length = round(strlen($content) / $preview);

$content = substr($content, $length / 3, $length);

header("Content-Type: {$id3_info['mime_type']}");

header("Content-Length: {$length}");

print_r($content);
```

Comment: You are sending a couple of headers … and then what? Nothing whatsoever, if that is all the code. Not sure what result you’d expect based on that.

Comment: Thank you..misorude for your response..i did some changes in code..can you review it again..or did you have any other idea to trim a audio file in php

Comment: i don't think you can just chop off some bytes and expect a playable audio file. seems like all you are doing is corrupting any possible output but then again, i am unfamiliar with the library.

Comment: Looks like you expected to be able to “trim” an mp3 by simply doing string operations on its binary content …? That of course won’t work (and is a _very_ naive assumption to begin with, if you don’t mind me saying.)

Comment: _“ am trying to trim audio file in php using getID3 library”_ - the getID3 library doesn’t do audio stream manipulation. It read and writes tag data included in such files, no more, no less. You’ll need to go and find yourself a library that can actually work with mp3 _audio_ data to begin with.

Comment: Actually issue is i have a php array of audio files.i need to set the audio files in a way that they will play for 40 second then stop.so i got the idea to trim the audio files before play